# How to access SharePoint with only username and password with TFA

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I am developing an application that needs access to anybody's SharePoint through their own individual user credentials i.e. username, password and TFA (TFA is my issue).

So far I have had simple success with:

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(server))
{
    clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(UserName, securePassword);
    Web web = clientContext.Web;
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Obviously this does not deal with TFA. I have searched, but all I can find are routines that need a clientID and Secret (which needs someone to fiddle in the back end of SharePoint for information) and most seem to rely on deprecated NuGet packages i.e. SharePointPnPCoreOnline (and PnP.Framework is beyond my ability to comprehend). I know other apps seem to be able to function by jumping you to blank webpage with a Microsoft login (One time only) and this seems to get the access required which persists.  I cannot find any clues as to what this process is doing or how to code/implement it.

I am programming at a pretty basic level, self taught, so simply need some pointers to get me on the right track and then I tend to try to make sense of what I find...but this challenge defeats me. Anyone able to assist?